# Using sass with aurelia style binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, aurelia

I'm fiddling with a project that uses Aurelia. I don't really know anything about it, so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology.

The project I'm looking at has most of the styles in the style tag at the head of the html page. Those html files have a js file with the same name. The css in the style tags appears to be importing javascript properties with this syntax: color: ${color}; as an example. I can vaguely understand what's happening, but was wondering how all of this communicates with each other because I've never seen javascript within css before.

I'm trying to switch all of the css over to sass, but am not sure if it's possible with Aurelia for the css values that change according to JS. Is there a way to put these styles in an external stylesheet while still using the ${} syntax to adapt to changes in JS?

Comment: Could you please post the code in question?

Comment: It really dpends on the context and the source used to produce that script tag. Something like the following linked file uses string interpolation (the ${...} syntax) with data-binding. If you bind a variable to a bound property (color in your example), the color value will change and string interpolation will update. As a result the css changes. The file: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/colors/md-colors.html